# How to purposely get a 409 HTTP Conflict response from a server?

Tags: java, spring, http

We are implementing a retry mechanism (using Spring Retry) for http 409 Conflict responses, which we sometimes get on the production server.

But we wonder how to purposely get a server to respond with a 409 status code? In our cases, the error seems to happen whenever we try to load a lot of data in parallel; since the probability of it happening seems quite random, is there a method to get it consistently for testing purposes?

Comment: Do you need the response for tests?

Comment: You can send a request to http://httpbin.org/status/409

Comment: You stand up a server that you explicitly program to do so?

Comment: Turing85 yes.
CherryDT thanks, didn't know it!
chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- sure, but what if I deploy the application and would like to avoid testing the retry code on production...?

Answer (score 3):

Well, There might be multiple possible ways to do so, You need to clarify where exactly you need 409 to be thrown ,

I assume (Its spring boot app) from one of your service (A) calls to another service/API(B) and you expect it to throw 409.

If that's the case, you can write **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)/@SpringBootTest** test and mock the response from service/API B with 409 and test your retry mechanism.

Comment: The unit testing and mocking is done and working already. But once the application is deployed, how can I ensure the mechanism will work in the 'real world'?